# Implicitly enable TensorFlow v2 behaviour in TensorFlow v1

Tags: python, tensorflow

As part of our migration to TensorFlow 2 I'd like to enable TensorFlow v2 behaviour in TensorFlow v1 (specifically TensorFlow 1.14). I'm aware that I can call `tf.enable_v2_behavior()` to do this, but I'd like to do this implicitly (via an environment variable or similar) without having to explicitly call this function.

The reason I want to do this is so that people don't forget to do this, and don't accidently end up with v1 behaviour. I can ensure that `tf.enable_v2_behavior()` is called before any tests are run, but then the underlying behaviour of our code may be different outside of the test environment (the tests may pass, but the code fails when run outside of the test environment).

Any environment variable would probably work, as I can pretty much guarantee that this is set in all our docker images, but I'm open to alternatives. I could do this on import of a specific module, but I can't guarantee that a particular module will always be imported (except for `tensorflow`!).

The docs for `enable_v2_behavior` state "This function is called in the main TensorFlow `__init__.py` file, user should not need to call it, except during complex migrations.", but this doesn't appear to be true (at least in TensorFlow 1.14; this is true for TensorFlow 2.0 I guess).

Comment: You can edit the installed tensorflow `__init__` file, or edit the `__init__` in your room package to call the function.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm not going to change TensorFlow's `__init__` file. Assuming you mean "own package", I can't guarantee that a particular package will always be imported.

Comment: Is this a public project? I would be very interested to see your code, or to read your experiences of this transition. See also [my related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60966376/best-practice-to-write-code-compatible-to-both-tensorflow-1-and-2).

Comment: @Albert Sorry, it's not public

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That actually exists, if you set the environment variable `TF2_BEHAVIOR` to `1` it will enable 2.x behavior. I have not found documentation about it, but you can see it in a comment in [the source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.15.0/tensorflow/python/compat/v2_compat.py#L30-L51):

```
# TF2 behavior is enabled if either 1) enable_v2_behavior() is called or
# 2) the TF2_BEHAVIOR=1 environment variable is set.  In the latter case,
# the modules below independently check if tf2.enabled().
```

I tested it in 1.15.0 and it seems to work:

```
import os
os.environ['TF2_BEHAVIOR'] = '1'
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.constant([1, 2, 3]))  # Eager mode is enabled
# tf.Tensor([1 2 3], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
print(tf.TensorShape([1, 2])[1])  # TensorShape dimensions are int
# 2
```

Comment: That works well, thanks! That comment doesn't exist in TF 1.14, but setting the TF2_BEHAVIOR environment variable seems to have the desired behaviour

Comment: Is it also possible to set the tensorflow 2 behaviour global to tensorflow 1 behaviour?

Comment: @Varlor You mean an environment variable that makes TF 2.x behave like 1.x (or do the equivalent of [`tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/disable_v2_behavior))? I don't think anything like that exists...

Comment: yes this is what i mean. Thats sad. I need somehow change the kind of tensorflow import. Because i have a module which is loaded and in which tensorflow is imported. I can not change this code. So i have to somehow change it in the upper level after or before the module is imported. Something like: if not int(tf.__version__[0]) <= 1:
    import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
    tf.disable_v2_behavior()